# ADT Version 23(20140702) Start as Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, adt

I've downloaded a new ADT version(20140702) from [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), but i just little bit curious, usually my ADT start with [Android Developer Tools splash screen](http://cdn.dice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/working.jpg), but after i downloaded a new version, it's open as [Eclipse Juno Splash Screen](http://blog.japila.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/eclipse-juno-logo.png).

I know ADT  is a plugin for the Eclipse IDE that is designed to give a powerful, integrated environment in which to build Android applications.

Thanks.

PS.

`I not updated my ADT, i just downloaded from that link and run eclipse.exe as usual`

Comment: I have read that currently the new ADT is bugged and you must download Eclipse Juno then install the ADT Plugin manually http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: Google is, pretty clearly, abandoning eclipse in favor of Studio.  It is true, the didn't even put the icons in the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of ADT has an issue. It doesn't work directly. Either use Android Studio or download Eclipse 4.4, and install ADT Plugin manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it's setup for the Windows version of ADT, however I'd like to share how to do it for the Mac OS version.

If your only concern is the splash screen and icon, you just have to tweak some files from the bundle.

***Note:*** *This is only tested in ADT Version 23 (20140702) downloaded from [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).*

1. For the splashscreen

   Go to your ADT bundle directory and open the `config.ini` file located in `eclipse/configuration/`.

   Replace the following:

   `osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform`

   to this:

   `osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package`

   then save the file.
2. And for the icon

   Just edit the `info.plist` inside `eclipse.app/Contents/` and change:

   `<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
       <string>Eclipse.icns</string>`

   to:

   `<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
       <string>`**`adt.icns`**`</string>`

   lastly, go to `eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS` and open the file `eclipse.ini` and modify:

   `-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns` to `-Xdock:icon=../Resources/adt.icns`

Hope this helps any Mac OS users of ADT out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any issue with it then you can download Eclipse from the official eclipse site and sdk from developer.android.

Comment: download Eclipse Luno from from official site of eclipse and sdk from developer.android